# get video html 5 duration after adding to html

Tags: jquery, css, html

I need to have video duration or video length after adding following html video tag so I can have this duration in a variable.

```
  $(".container").append('<video  Id = "DivImage" src="Video/Video02.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay  /> ');
```

like this :

```
var duration = document.getElementById("DivImage").duration;
```

But unfortunately it does not work. Please consider that I need this duration to change the parameter of setInterval function to the length of the video file. like :

```
  timer = setInterval(function () { cycleItems() }, duration);
```

Comment: video has an opening and closing tag `<video src="" controls>text to be displayed if browser doesn't support video tag</video>` and have you included jquery ?

Comment: Yes, I have a collection of videos and images. I need once video is displayed, it will last by the end of video. images has predefined time but video must be last by the end of video.

Comment: there is a) a loadedmetadata event, which is fired as soon as the video duration is known to the browser and b) there is also an ended event if the video is ended. maybe you want to use the ended event to change slides???

Comment: @ alexander farkas  thank you,loadedmetadata  help me to solve the problem

Comment: @alexanderfarkas  How can I accept your accept?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var duration = document.getElementById("DivImage").duration;
```

Comment: as i try, i can't get the video duration Immediately after i append the video tag.

Comment: it return me the Nan value

Answer (score 0):

you might need to wait for the video to be loaded, which isn't on dom ready... try this:

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/0fdcaa3ffe74f72c35a3b6f2ef15d18c)

1. declaring `timer` var for `cycleItems()` outside current scope

   - this way, it wont be undefined when you reference it later.
2. creating and appending your video
3. setting our interval to a variable, `durTimer` so we can reference it later to clear it once we have our duration.
4. ask whether our video is ready w/ `if ($vid[0].readyState) {`

   - basically if it isn't ready `readyState` will evaluate to a "false-y" value; when video is ready, `readyState` will equal 4.
   - so if isn't zero, execute the code inside the block `if(){}` statement
5. get the `video.duration` property and set that to a `duration` variable

   - note that we're using the `$vid[0]` to get a non-jquery element.
6. set your `timer` variable to an interval containing your `cycleItems()` function, and set it's duration to `1000*video.duration` so it'll be in ms.
7. I'm adding some HTML to display the duration
8. clear the "duration checking" interval since we don't need it anymore.

if the video's ready state wasn't greater than 0, or === 4(which is ready), it skips the code in if block, and resets the timer to "try again" in another 100ms.

```
$(function() {
    /*1*/
    var timer;
    /*2*/
    var $vid = $('<video  id="divImage" src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm" autoplay/>').appendTo($(".container"));
    /*3*/  
    var durTimer = setInterval(function() {
      /*4*/
      if ($vid[0].readyState) {

        /*5*/
        var duration = $vid[0].duration;

        /*6*/
        timer = setInterval(function () { cycleItems() }, duration*1000);
        /*7*/
        $('.container')[0].innerHTML += '<p>'+duration+'</p>';
        /*8*/
        clearInterval(durTimer);
      }
    }, 100);

});
```

[image: bunny]

Comment: thank you, for your time. firstly could you let me know how could you get the duration through your code? how does it work? I think exactly you said, my problem is that my video need to be loaded, but i still don't know that how I can solve my problem.

Comment: alright. so... how i'm doing it can be easily looked up; it's pretty standard, but check my upcoming edit for a step-by-step.

Comment: sorrym @AliHosseini, I left a part out of the actual answer, not the demo: `duration = $vid[0].duration`. no wonder you were confused. lol.